# Can't explain syntax error in bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax-error

In my script I wrote down this control expression:

```
if ! [[ $start -gt $(cut -f3 rooms.txt) -a $end -gt $(cut -f4 rooms.txt) ]]; then
    echo "Invalid prenotation";
    ./prenote.sh;
fi
```

`start` and `end` are simple numbers. Each record in file `rooms.txt` is built in this way:

```
room;date;start;end;username
```

There are non blank spaces in the record.
When I run the script I get a syntax error near the if statement.

Can someone tell me where the error is? Thanks

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ would have caught this error for you.

Comment: Confusingly, inside `[[` `-a filename` is  true if the file exists.  So `-a` has a different meaning inside `[` (test) and `[[`.  By the way, you don't need a semi-colon at the end of every line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator `-a` for "and" is not valid in `[[`...`]]` conditionals.  Use `&&` instead.

But if you're doing numeric comparisons in bash, it might make more sense to use `((`...`))` instead of `[[`...`]]`. Then the normal relational operators are numeric instead of string-based, so you can use `>` instead of `-gt`:

```
if ! (( start > $(cut -f3 rooms.txt) && end > $(cut -f4 rooms.txt) )); then
...
fi
```

However, this approach only works if `rooms.txt` has only one line; otherwise, you'll get syntax errors when the `$(cut...)` commands produce more than one number. I'm not sure exactly what problem you're solving, but an approach something like this might be fruitful:

```
while read _ _ low high _; do 
  if ! (( start > low && end > high )); then
    ...
  fi
done <rooms.txt
```